# How to extract month and year from given date in python in azure ml

Tags: python, azure

I was working in azure ml for the past few days. I came up with a dataset which consists of date in the below format

> mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss

I want to extract month and year from it by writing python code in azure ml. I am trying the following code:

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    import pandas as pd
    dates = pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['Order Date'])
    dates = dates.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
    dataframe1['Order Date'] = dates
    # Execution logic goes here
    print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1))
```

But I am getting an error saying that NTType there is no attribute with the name strftime.
Can anyone tell me what's the issue here and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.dt` to access the datetime methods.

**Ex:**

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(data['Order Date']).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: Now it is showing the error as 'str' has no attribute with the name 'dt'

Comment: Can you post your DF?

Comment: Updated snippet. Can you try now?

Comment: Ya I got it the dates where in string format I converted them to date object. Now it's working.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: sloved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL transformation use SQL query to cast your datetime.