# how to extract month and year from a given date in th form of a string

Tags: python, azure

good Evening,
I have a dataframe which consists of order date, dispatch date each having dates in the format 02-25-2013. I want to extract month and year from these dates and I want to generate new columns in my dataset as Order_Mt, Order_yr, Dispatch_Mt, Dispatch_Yr. I tried to extract by using strptime(). But no use. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The dates are in string format

Comment: Please avoid asking duplicate questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128665/how-to-extract-month-and-year-from-given-date-in-python-in-azure-ml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to datetime format in pandas python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.dt` to access the datetime methods.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order Date': ["02-25-2013"]})
df["Order Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Order Date"])
df["Order_Mt"] = df["Order Date"].dt.month
df["Order_yr"] = df["Order Date"].dt.year
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Order Date  Order_Mt  Order_yr
0 2013-02-25         2      2013
```